# How to add path variable for File vault tool(VLT) AEM eclipse integration

Tags: eclipse, variables, path, aem, filevault

Integrating FileVault with Eclipse usually requires setting up filevault path variable.I have described the steps below

Answer (score 0):

Copy the FileVault archive file from the cq-quickstart/opt/filevault directory of your installation. Copy either filevalut.tgz or filevault.zip, depending on your operating system.NOTE: You can also download the latest version of FileVault from Package Share. Extract the archive. Add /vault-cli-/bin to your environment PATH so that the command files vlt or vlt.bat are accessed as appropriate.

Path variable setup:
    1)vim ~/.bash_profile
    2)PATH="/User/Documents/AEM/AEM_6.1/crx-quickstart/opt/helpers/vault-cli-
    3.1.16/bin:${PATH}"
    export PATH
    3)source ~/.bash_profile

For example, /crx-quickstart/opt/helpers/vault-cli-2.4.8/bin. Open a command line shell and execute vlt –help. Make sure it displays the results.